# Python uninstalling updated packages to install old ones then creating errors as old package is incompatible

Tags: python-3.x, installation, conda, python-sphinx

I am trying to run some model code, which requires the super_gradients package. I tried to install it using anaconda and the following code:
`pip install super-gradients`.
However it is not installing onto my laptop, as it keeps saying my version of sphinx is outdated, but my attempts to update it have been unsuccessful.

Initally while resolving it came up with the following error message.
[First error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLWLC.png)
I thought that if I update my version of sphinx it should fix the issue. So I then installed sphinx manually, which gave me the confirmation that sphinx 5.0.2 had been installed successfully.
But then when I tried to install super_gradients again it uninstalled the new version of sphinx for the old one and then gave me the same error message.
[Second error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpzOZ.png).

I also tried installing super-gradients from this link (https://pypi.org/simple/super-gradients/) and while I think installation was successful, I'm not sure because my system can't detect the package (and I can't trace it).